# How to change a global constant defined in a 3rd party library

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I use the latest SVN source of Indy , and there is a global integer constant defined in a unit called IdIOHandler.pas, in my special case I need a different value for that global constant value, and to avoid manual modification each time the local SVN working copy is updated from the SVN server, I'm looking for a way to permanently change that value without affecting other users of Indy.

I think one way to do that is to ask the maintainers to change that constant into a variable, but I'm still wondering if there is a way to hack the value of a constant in the memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commonly used way to apply such changes to third party libraries with Subversion are "[Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html)".

> The solution to this problem is to use vendor branches. A vendor
>   branch is a directory tree in your own version control system that
>   contains information provided by a third-party entity, or vendor. Each
>   version of the vendor's data that you decide to absorb into your
>   project is called a vendor drop. (...)

With this technique your local Subversion repository would also contain a copy of the Indy sources and your patches.

Comment: Thanks for the help, read the page you pointed to, it's way too complex... However, you inspired me to use a text comparing tool when updating my local copy of the external library, which should do what I want :)